# Same request to server with form-data works in postman but do not works in axios why?

Tags: php, rest, post, axios, postman

So, when i send request with form-data using POSTMAN i get the valid PHPSESSID which i can use to LOGIN to the website and parse authorized page. But, when i trying to do same request from axios or fetch or another request-tool website it gives me invalid PHPSESSID. And i dont know why?

[postman form-data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuClp.png)

[postman headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nT0lA.png)

[postman console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1wd1.png)

[axios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBcb8.png)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not sending the formData correctly.

You need to use the [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) class, and `append` all the keys you want to the formData, like:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('key', 'value'); 

axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: <your url>,
  data: formData,
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
})
```

---

If you want to use the `qs` package, then do:

```
let data = qs.stringify({
  username: 'somelogin',
  password: 'somepassword',
})

let config = {
  method: 'post',
  url: <your url>,
  data,
  headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
}

axios
  .request(config)
```

Comment: I write the same code you tell but it still not working.

Comment: Whats the error you are getting? Also, which of my 2 solutions did you use?

Comment: Firstly thank you for helping.
It doesnt gives an arrow server just sending me invalid PHPSESSID cookie.

Also, i have checked the request data from console.log(request) so i think i send form-data correctly 
`method: 'post',
 url: 'http://kabinet.unec.edu.az',
data:'LoginForm%5Busername%5D=somelogin&LoginForm%5Bpassword%5D=somepass&yt0=Daxil%20ol'`

Comment: @MuradRahmanov From your postman, can you copy the CURL of your request, and add it here?